# How to initialize Array dynamically without specifying array size in C

Tags: c

I need not specify the length of the array in the program. Instead, I 
have to take array input (string) from the console and dynamically I 
have to allocate memory for the given input array.
Can you please help me.(In C language)

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!msg/comp.lang.perl/wu0T7a9orc0/3Q4PVIbEzZUJ

Comment: possible duplicate of [dynamic memory allocation and dynamic array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481188/dynamic-memory-allocation-and-dynamic-array)

Answer (score 0):

Use `malloc` to allocate memory on the heap for your array.

Comment: I wrote a code like this and got segmentation fault.
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()

{

char *ar;

int size;
printf("Enetr size of the array:");
scanf("%d",size);
ar=(char *)malloc (size);
printf("\nEnter a String:");
scanf("%s",&ar);

printf("\n\n\nString is: %s",ar);
return 0;

}

Comment: You have to pass scanf a pointer where it can store the value: scanf("%d", &size);

Answer (score 0):

E.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *getString(FILE* fp){
    char *str;
    int ch;
    size_t len = 0, size = 16;
    str = realloc(NULL, sizeof(char)*size);//size is start size
    if(!str)return str;
    while(EOF!=(ch=fgetc(fp)) && ch != '\n'){
        str[len++]=ch;
        if(len==size){
            str = realloc(str, sizeof(char)*(size+=16));//expand size
            if(!str)return str;
        }
    }
    str[len++]='\0';

    return realloc(str, sizeof(char)*len);
}

int main(void){
    char *str;

    printf("input string : ");
    str = getString(stdin);
    printf("%s\n", str);

    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

An pointer in C can be used as an array. In fact `some_pointer[0]` can be used instead of `*some_pointer`. So if you ensure that some_pointer points to a memory area with the needed size, you can use that pointer just like an array. You can use `malloc` to get that memory from the memory manager:

```
some_type *some_pointer;
some_pointer = (some_type *)malloc(sizeof(some_type) * size_of_your_array);
/* Some code that uses some_pointer[i] with 0 <= i < size_of_your_array */
free(some_pointer);
/* Some code NOT using the pointer */
```

Note the `free` at the end of the code. This will free the memory. If you did not use that `free`, the memory will be consumed while your program is running (at least).

Further note that the size information on the array is not stored (in contrast to an array, where sizeof can be used, since the array size is part of the type definition).

Comment: No, an array is *not* the same as a pointer. An array sometimes "decays" to a pointer, but they're not the same.

Comment: @unwind: Can you please specify the difference between a c array and a (valid) c pointer? I think, they are actually the same, since there is no size information stored in c.

Comment: A lack of "size information" is not the sole differentiator of, well... anything.  Arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays.  There are many differences, all well documented here in SO and elsewhere.