# Dynamic memory allocation for arrays C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

So today at the university we had this simple program where we had to input the heights of n number of students and then print out the sum of the heights. The heights were stored in an array. Now that was simple enough - however, we started the problem with a fixed number of students, 5 in my example. Then I asked the professor how would I solve the problem if the number of students wasn't already defined and she told me that I'd have to use lists and dynamic array element allocation. We did not reach that yet so I came here to ask for help since I'm interested in solving it like that.

Could someone show/explain or give me some guidelines on how I should approach the problem. Here is how the problem was solved in class.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main(){


    int height[5], sum=0, i;
    int numOfStudents=5;
    float average;

    for(i=0; i<numOfStudents; i++){  
        printf("Type in the height of the %d. student: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &height[i]);

        sum+=height[i];
    }
    printf("\n Sum of all heights is: %d. There were %d students", sum, numOfStudents);

return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Look into the `malloc()` function located in `stdlib.h` you can declare `int *height` and then read in a value for `n` and do something similar to `malloc(sizeof(int) * n);`. Read up on the function though so you understand it.

Comment: Why are you asking this here? There are endless resources that will teach you programming or specifically C, one of them is your textbook. If you want to study, do it.

Comment: And don't forget to call ```free()``` once you call ```malloc()```

Comment: Nothing wrong with asking basic questions. But it's good form to at least do some research on your own first. A minute or two of searching should find you lots of existing help like [dynamic memory allocation and dynamic array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481188/dynamic-memory-allocation-and-dynamic-array)

Comment: Note that your code does not need the array at all..

Comment: ..and even if you did need to keep a record of the individual student heights, there is a simpler solution than using dynamic array element allocation:  'int height[500000]'.  Try and blow that one with manual entry:)

Comment: It is an unusual question because the student wants to achieve more than Prof asked. But if OP thirsts for knowledge... you'll need to sharpen your problem solving skills too!

Comment: You could also completely forget about memory and arrays and just add the height of the new student to the sum...

Comment: Yeah.. it's a difficult one.  The prof. will want the student to learn about dynamic allocation, but most of the experienced engineers in here would just declare a massive array and be done with it:)

Comment: Given some of the questions posted on SO from our esteemed centres of academic excellence, another solution would be to chainsaw all the students to the same height, so you would only need to know how many there are :)

Comment: I apologize for not searching a bit more before posting, I will remember that for my future posts. Thanks to everyone who replied.

Comment: :-) and define `const double student_height_meters = 1.50` globally.

Comment: it is a very bad idea to #include header files that are not used.  It is also a bad idea to #include header files that are a)not used and b) are not portable.   I.E. the header file: `conio.h` is not portable and none of its' contents are being used by the posted code, so it should not be #include'd

Comment: the `average` variable is not used.  so this is a poor example of a class room coding project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define `height` as a pointer

`int *height;`

Then allocate dinamically memory to store the array elements

`height = malloc( sizeof(int) * numOfStudents );`

Note that the appropriate size (in bytes) is calculated as the product of the size of an `int` by the number of array items.

This approach implies that the size of the array is known beforehand.

As memory is allocated dinamically it's your duty to free it with

`free(height);`

as you don't need the array anymore.

---

The whole thing becomes

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int *height, sum=0, i;
    int numOfStudents=5;

    height = malloc( sizeof(int) * numOfStudents );

    for(i=0; i<numOfStudents; i++)
    {
        printf("Type in the height of the %d. student: ", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &height[i]);

        sum+=height[i];
    }

    printf("\n Sum of all heights is: %d. There were %d students", sum, numOfStudents);

    free( height );

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: This helped, thank you. I will now try to study malloc function more and try it out in some other examples. Thank you once again.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to understand that 'list' is an abstract data type, which looks like this:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/37/Singly_linked_list.png/220px-Singly_linked_list.png

It consists of a number of nodes connecting to each other like a chain, and each node maintains its own value.

An easy way to implement this data structure in c language is as follows:

```
struct Node {
    int val;
    struct Node* next;
};
```

Where 'val' stores the value, and 'next' stores the address to next node. Treat 'struct Node*' as a whole, and you will learn that represents 'struct Node pointer' which literately points to the address of a node.

And now you can create a list of 2 elements like this:

```
struct Node* n1 = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
n1->val = 200;
struct Node* n2 = malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
n2->val = 300;
n1->next = n2;
```

Keep appending elements and you can create a list 'Node's of whatever length you want.

Comment: Why the necessity to do something like this when it's possible to use a dynamically allocated array?

Comment: Because professor told Bayaz that "You have to use lists and dynamic array element allocation.", and my code is the most common way to implement 'list' in c language.

Comment: Still, this method is real overkill for what the OP is trying to do

Comment: If you think it's just an "overkill", would you please revoke you down vote?

Comment: I'm not  the one who downvoted you...

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. Nevermind.